# How to check if the received mail is a notification for a failed sent mail

Tags: jakarta-mail, ibm-domino

If I send a mail to someone, and put wrong email address. Then a notification mail comes back saying that email id does not exist.
If we want to do this process automatically by a java code using javamail api. Then how to check if the received mail is a notification for failed sent mail or not.

I have tried to do this first with gmail. And in gmail, there is a header "x-failed-receipient" which will be not null if the mail is a notification for failed sent mail.

Now I am trying to do this with IBM domino.
I want to know if this "x-failed-receipient" header thing is same for all, or is this unique to gmail and IBM Domino will have something unique for it.